# How to process bitand operation in Informix with column in hex string format

Tags: sql, informix

In table I have string column which contains a hex value. For example value '000000000000000a' means 10. Now I need to process `bitand` operation: `bitand(tableName.hexColumn, ?)`. When I read the Informix specification of this function it needs 2 int. So my question is: what is the simpler way to process this operation?

PS: Probably there is no solution in Informix so I will have to create my own `bitandhexstring` function where input will be 2 string and hex form but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of issues to be dealt with:

1. Your hex string has 16 digits, so the values are presumably (in general) 64-bit quantities.  That means you need to be sure that the BITAND function has a variant that handles BIGINT (or perhaps INT8 — I'm not going to mention INT8 again, but it is nominally an option when BIGINT is mentioned) data.
2. You need to convert your hex string to a BIGINT.
3. It is not clear whether you'll need to convert the result BIGINT back to a hex string.

Some testing with Informix 11.70.FC6 on Mac OS X 10.10.4 shows that BITAND is safe with 64-bit numbers.  That's good news!

The HEX function, when passed a BIGINT, returns a CHAR(20) string that starts with `0x` and contains a hex representation of the number, so that more or less addresses point 3.  The residual issue is 'how to convert 16-byte strings of hex digits to a BIGINT value'.  Nominally, a cast operation like:

```
 CAST('0xde3962e8c68a8001' AS BIGINT)
```

should do the job (but see below).  There may be a better way of doing it than a brute-force and ignorance stored procedure, but I'm not immediately sure what it is.

---

<sup>*Caveat Lector.*</sup>

While testing this, I tried two queries:

```
SELECT bi, HEX(bi)                         FROM Test_BigInt;
SELECT bi, HEX(bi), SUBSTR(HEX(bi), 3, 16) FROM Test_BigInt;
```

on a table `Test_BigInt` with a single column `bi` of type BIGINT (not null, as it happened, but that's not material).

The first query worked fine.  The type of the `HEX(bi)` expression was CHAR(20) and the values were like

```
                   0    0x0000000000000000
 6898532535585831936    0x5fbc82ca87117c00
-2300268458811555839    0xe013ce0628808001
```

The second query sort of worked for small values of `bi` (0, 1, 2), but generated an error `-1215: Value exceeds limit of INTEGER precision` when the values got large.  The problem is not the SUBSTR function directly.  This was testing with Informix 11.70.FC6 on Mac OS X 10.10.4 — tested on 2015-07-08.  The following pair of queries worked as expected (which is my justification for claiming that the problem is not in the SUBSTR function per se).

```
SELECT bi, HEX(bi) AS hex_bi FROM Test_BigInt INTO TEMP t;
SELECT bi, hex_bi, SUBSTR(hex_bi, 3, 16) FROM t;
```

It seems to be an interaction problem when the result of HEX is used in a string operation context.  I first got the problem when trying to concatenate an empty string to the result of HEX: `HEX(bi) || ''`.  That turns out to be unnecessary given that the result of HEX is reported as CHAR(20), but also indicates SUBSTR is not directly at fault.

I also tried CAST to get the hex string converted to BIGINT:

```
SELECT CAST('0xde3962e8c68a8001' AS BIGINT) FROM dual;
BIGINT
-964001791
SELECT HEX(CAST('0xde3962e8c68a8001' AS BIGINT)) FROM dual;
CHAR(18)
0xffffffffc68a8001
```

Grrr!  Something is mishandling the conversion.  This is not new software (well over 2 years old), but the chances are that unless someone else has spotted the bug, it has not yet been fixed, even in the latest version.

I've reported this through back-channels to IBM/Informix.

---

#### Stored procedures to convert hex string to BIGINT

```
CREATE PROCEDURE hexval(c CHAR(1)) RETURNING INTEGER;
    RETURN INSTR("0123456789abcdef", lower(c)) - 1;
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE PROCEDURE hexstr_to_bigint(ival VARCHAR(18)) RETURNING bigint;
    DEFINE oval DECIMAL(20,0);
    DEFINE i,j,len INTEGER;
    LET ival = LOWER(ival);
    IF (ival[1,2] = '0x') THEN LET ival = ival[3,18]; END IF;
    LET len = LENGTH(ival);
    LET oval = 0;
    FOR i = 1 TO len
        LET j = hexval(SUBSTR(ival, i, 1));
        LET oval = oval * 16 + j;
    END FOR;
    IF (oval > 9223372036854775807) THEN
        LET oval = oval - 18446744073709551616;
    END IF;
    RETURN oval;
END PROCEDURE;
```

Casual testing:

```
execute procedure hexstr_to_bigint('000A');
10
execute procedure hexstr_to_bigint('FFff');
65535
execute procedure hexstr_to_bigint('FFFFffffFFFFffff');
-1
execute procedure hexstr_to_bigint('0XFFFFffffFFFFffff');
-1
execute procedure hexstr_to_bigint('000000000000000A');
10
```

Those values are correct.

Comment: thank you your answer.  In question I forgot to add that I need bitand operation in where clause like: bitand(tableName.hexColumn, ?) != 0. So when I understand it right your suggest is to create sql like: SELECT * FROM tableName where bitand(CAST('0x' || tableName.hexColumn AS BIGINT),?) != 0;  PS: there is dual table in Informix :) ?

Comment: I create a table called DUAL in each of my databases.  Informix has `sysmaster:sysdual` (or, in full, `sysmaster:informix.sysdual`) which is more efficient but less convenient; I go for convenience over efficiency.  `CREATE TABLE dual
(
    dummy CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'x' NOT NULL CHECK (dummy = 'x') PRIMARY KEY
) EXTENT SIZE 16 NEXT SIZE 16;
INSERT INTO dual VALUES('x');

REVOKE ALL ON dual FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT SELECT ON dual TO PUBLIC;`

Comment: As to the use of BITAND, then what you suggest is what I think should work, but it doesn't work directly because of bugs (embarrassing, but so).  I've added a pair of stored procedures to the answer that jointly convert a hex string of up to 64 bits to the corresponding (signed) BIGINT, but it won't be all that fast.

Comment: yea I try it and it can cast just 28 bit '0x000000000FFFFFFF'::BIGINT (what should be equivalent to cast) return right result 268435455 but  '0x00000000FFFFFFFF'::BIGINT return just -1. You are sure it is bug not feauture ?

Comment: nice thx for the procedure. Now I hope that my version of informix (12+) also support bitand operation with bigint

Comment: As a 64-bit number, 0x00000000FFFFFFFF is not equivalent to -1; that's valid for a 32-bit number, but you'd normally write that as 0xFFFFFFFF without the extra zeros.